# Analogy between two similar problems in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

The two most common problems in combinatorics that I have come across are: **selecting** some objects **from** a set, and **distributing** some objects **into** a set type problems.

For example, imagine you have $n$ objects that you need to choose from $r$ different types of objects, where order doesn't matter and repetition is allowed.

Another question is, you have $n$ objects that you need to put into $r$ different boxes.

In both cases, the solution is given by: $$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{n!(r-1)!}$$

I've seen this solution derived using the stars and bars method for the distribution problem.

However, is it derived in the same way for the -choosing- problem ? If so, there must be some connection between choosing and distributing type problems. In the language of combinatorics, does choose $n$ objects from $r$ types of objects, mean the same thing as distributing $n$ objects into $r$ types of bins? Or are these two fundamentally different problems that just happen to have similar mathematics working behind them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same. Imagine you do the "choosing" by taking $n$ stickers and putting them on the chosen objects. Now you're "distributing" the stickers into $r$ "bins" corresponding to the types of objects.

Comment: Can I say it in this way, that both selecting and distribution problems ask how many ways  combinations of $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i=n$, and hence they have the same solution ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to look at it too. You're counting the integer tuples $(x_1,...,x_k)$ that have each $x_i\ge0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=n$.